# Angular: Error 'Cannot read property 'hide' of undefined' when closing a modal

Tags: angular

Using Angular 6 here. I have a app component which has a button. On click of this button I try to open my child component in my modal and bind some data to it. While everything works except closing the modal which gives me error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'hide' of undefined"

I am opening the modal as:

```
this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(Child1Component,
          { initialState: { data }, ignoreBackdropClick: true, animated: true, keyboard: true, class: 'modal' });
```

And in my child html closing as:

```
<button type="button" class="close pull-right" aria-label="Close" (click)="modalRef.hide()">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
```

I expect the on closing the modal it should close and not give error.

Demo: https://angular-modal-pop-wsesd4.stackblitz.io

Editor: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-modal-pop-wsesd4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should update your child to inject `BsModalRef` and then call hide on when button is clicked it:

```
import { Component, TemplateRef, Output, EventEmitter  } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { BsDropdownModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';
import { BsDatepickerModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/datepicker';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { BsModalService, BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';

@Component({
  selector: 'child1-app',
  templateUrl: './child1.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class Child1Component  {

  data: string[];
  @Output() onHide = new EventEmitter<void>();
  constructor(private modalService: BsModalService, private appService: AppService, 
      private bsModalRef: BsModalRef) {
  }

  ngOnInit() { }



  doHide() {
    this.bsModalRef.hide();
  }

}
```

from HTML:

```
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="doHide()">Close</button>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get the modal reference by injecting a BsModalRef in the component, like this:

```
constructor ( public modalRef: BsModalRef, private modalService: BsModalService, private appService: AppService) {   }
```

And now you can erase the `modalRef` property from your component.